# Does not load the post if you do not fill in all the fields

Tags: android, firebase

Help solve the problem. Now, if you do not fill all the fields, shows an endless Progress Bar. Is it possible to make EditText necessary, without them you can not send a post, and the image is not necessary. tried to install a check on the filling of fields, and and if the user tries to continue the robot with the application without filling the fields, output an error. But if no image is selected - the post is not published (the endless ProgresBar)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");


mSelectImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);

mPostTitle =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleField);
mPostDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descField);
mSubmitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }
});

mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        startposting();
    }
});
}

private void startposting() {

mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Post..");
mProgress.show();

final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val)&& mImageUri!=null){

    StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Blog_images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

            DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
            newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
            newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
            newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUri.toString());


            mProgress.dismiss();

            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

            mProgress.setMessage("Uploading " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
            mProgress.show();
        }
    });
}


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if ( requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
    mImageUri = data.getData();
    mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: To clarify me, you want to do this if the edittext is empty you want to inform the user that is empty and not show the progresso bar rigth?

Comment: Not really, the main problem is that the post does not load if I did not select an image